# XMLHttpRequest not sending 'Via'

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Here is my problem:
When performing an AJAX call with XMLHttpRequest
it doesn't add the 'Via' header to the request.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.poodle.com/", true);
...
xhr.setRequestHeader("Via", "Hello World");
...
xhr.send(null);
```

Here is the mapped info:

```
(Request-Line)  GET / HTTP/1.1
Host    poodle.com:80
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept  text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8
Accept-Language null
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Content-Type    application/json
Referer http://www.poodle.com/
Cookie  JSESSIONID=AB35C81E78FCE769187A8FD4611C3DD7
Connection  keep-alive
```

But when I use this instead it works, but I can't use this in a real web page (only Firefox Addon).

```
var xhr = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `Via` header in JavaScript is explicitly disallowed by the [W3C XHR spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method):

> Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match for one of the following headers:
>
> - `Accept-Charset`
> - `Accept-Encoding`
> - ...
> - `Upgrade`
> - `User-Agent`
> - **`Via`**
>
> *Note: The above headers are controlled by the user agent to let it control those aspects of transport. This guarantees data integrity to some extent.*